# Read a list of text files in R based on part of their name

Tags: r, regex, list, file, directory

I am using the below lines to read one text file. But, I need to include to read a list of text files but not all. How can I achieve this in R?

I have multiple folders in C:/data path. ie. 1998_Data, 1999_Data....so on and each folder has text files 01.txt...49.txt.

Thanks in advance.

```
startingDir<-"C:/Data"
files <- list.files(path = startingDir,pattern = "24.txt",recursive=T,full.names=T)
```

I included the line below but it does not read all 3 files in the list.
Any suggestions?

```
my_files <- c("24.txt","01.txt","10.txt")
files <- list.files(path = startingDir,pattern = my_files,recursive=T,full.names=T)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `pattern` expects a regular expression:

```
thepattern <- "24\\.txt|01\\.txt|10\\.txt"
files <- list.files(path = startingDir,
                    pattern = thepattern,
                    recursive=TRUE,
                    full.names=TRUE)
```

Keep in mind you have to escape the dot, as it is otherwise interpreted as "anything".

If you want to automate this, you can do the following:

```
my_files <- c("24.txt","01.txt","10.txt")
my_files <- gsub(".","\\.",my_files, fixed = TRUE)
my_pattern <- paste(my_files, collapse = "|")
```

you need `fixed = TRUE` in `gsub` to avoid the dot to be read as "anything". See also `?regex`

Comment: Thanks. Your solution above seems working. But, your code for automation does not work. It does not read all the files but just read the first text file in the list.

Comment: @user3408139 My bad, I used `sep` instead of `collapse`. Updated the code so it creates the correct regex.